# AWS S3 forces creating a folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm completely new to S3 and I'm trying to deploy an application.
I'm using this CLI command

```
aws s3 cp --recursive --acl public-read ./www s3://my_bucket123
```

`./www` is the build folder containing all the static files

a folder is created and inside it are all the files I deployed, I want the files to be outside of the folder and not inside

I'm using WSL as a command line tool on windows

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csQ61.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
aws s3 cp --recursive --acl public-read www/ s3://my_bucket123/
```

Or:

```
aws s3 sync --acl public-read www/ s3://my_bucket123/
```

Comment: the second one worked, thanks